# LinqDataSource with complex SQL

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, telerik

I have a rather long combinations of SQL statements to give me a 3 row result that I want to use in a Telerik Ticker. The Telerik Ticker as far as I can see will only accept Linq or Entity data sources.

So I have a Ticker with as `DataSourceID = "LinqDataSource1"` which has an `OnSelecting` Event.

My code behind has...

```
Protected Sub LinqDataSource1_Selecting(sender As Object, e As LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs) Handles LinqDataSource1.Selecting 

Dim db As New TestDataContext 

Dim tickerquery As New StringBuilder 

tickerquery.Append("DECLARE @ALL_Total int ") 
tickerquery.Append("DECLARE @ABC_Total int ") 
tickerquery.Append("DECLARE @XYZ_Total int ") 
tickerquery.Append("DECLARE @ALL_TypeA int ") 
tickerquery.Append("DECLARE @ABC_TypeA int ") 
tickerquery.Append("DECLARE @XYZ_TypeA int ") 
tickerquery.Append("DECLARE @ALL_TypeB int ") 
tickerquery.Append("DECLARE @ABC_TypeB int ") 
tickerquery.Append("DECLARE @XYZ_TypeB int ") 
tickerquery.Append("DECLARE @ALL_TypeC int ") 
tickerquery.Append("DECLARE @ABC_TypeC int ") 
tickerquery.Append("DECLARE @XYZ_TypeC int ") 
tickerquery.Append("DECLARE @ALL_TypeD int ") 
tickerquery.Append("DECLARE @ABC_TypeD int ") 
tickerquery.Append("DECLARE @XYZ_TypeD int ") 
tickerquery.Append("DECLARE @ALL_TypeE int ") 
tickerquery.Append("DECLARE @ABC_TypeE int ") 
tickerquery.Append("DECLARE @XYZ_TypeE int ") 

tickerquery.Append("DECLARE @ALL_Title nvarchar(3) ") 
tickerquery.Append("DECLARE @ABC_Title nvarchar(3) ") 
tickerquery.Append("DECLARE @XYZ_Title nvarchar(3) ") 
tickerquery.Append("SET @ALL_Title = 'ALL' ") 
tickerquery.Append("SET @ABC_Title = 'ABC' ") 
tickerquery.Append("SET @XYZ_Title = 'XYZ' ") 
tickerquery.Append("DECLARE @Count_Tbl table (Title nvarchar(3), Total int, TypeA int, TypeB int, TypeC int, TypeD int, TypeE int) ") 

tickerquery.Append("SELECT @ALL_Total = (SELECT Count(ProdID) FROM Products) ") 
tickerquery.Append("SELECT @ABC_Total = (SELECT Count(ProdID) FROM Products WHERE Category = 'ABC') ") 
tickerquery.Append("SELECT @XYZ_Total = (SELECT Count(ProdID) FROM Products WHERE Category = 'XYZ') ") 
tickerquery.Append("SELECT @ALL_TypeA = (SELECT Count(ProdID) FROM Products WHERE Productstatus = 'TypeA') ") 
tickerquery.Append("SELECT @ABC_TypeA = (SELECT Count(ProdID) FROM Products WHERE Category = 'ABC' AND Productstatus = 'TypeA') ") 
tickerquery.Append("SELECT @XYZ_TypeA = (SELECT Count(ProdID) FROM Products WHERE Category = 'XYZ' AND Productstatus = 'TypeA') ") 
tickerquery.Append("SELECT @ALL_TypeB = (SELECT Count(ProdID) FROM Products WHERE Productstatus = 'TypeB') ") 
tickerquery.Append("SELECT @ABC_TypeB = (SELECT Count(ProdID) FROM Products WHERE Category = 'ABC' AND Productstatus = 'TypeB') ") 
tickerquery.Append("SELECT @XYZ_TypeB = (SELECT Count(ProdID) FROM Products WHERE Category = 'XYZ' AND Productstatus = 'TypeB') ") 
tickerquery.Append("SELECT @ALL_TypeC = (SELECT Count(ProdID) FROM Products WHERE Productstatus = 'TypeC') ") 
tickerquery.Append("SELECT @ABC_TypeC = (SELECT Count(ProdID) FROM Products WHERE Category = 'ABC' AND Productstatus = 'TypeC') ") 
tickerquery.Append("SELECT @XYZ_TypeC = (SELECT Count(ProdID) FROM Products WHERE Category = 'XYZ' AND Productstatus = 'TypeC') ") 
tickerquery.Append("SELECT @ALL_TypeD = (SELECT Count(ProdID) FROM Products WHERE Productstatus = 'TypeD') ") 
tickerquery.Append("SELECT @ABC_TypeD = (SELECT Count(ProdID) FROM Products WHERE Category = 'ABC' AND Productstatus = 'TypeD') ") 
tickerquery.Append("SELECT @XYZ_TypeD = (SELECT Count(ProdID) FROM Products WHERE Category = 'XYZ' AND Productstatus = 'TypeD') ") 
tickerquery.Append("SELECT @ALL_TypeE = (SELECT Count(ProdID) FROM Products WHERE Productstatus <> 'TypeD') ") 
tickerquery.Append("SELECT @ABC_TypeE = (SELECT Count(ProdID) FROM Products WHERE Category = 'ABC' AND Productstatus = 'TypeE') ") 
tickerquery.Append("SELECT @XYZ_TypeE = (SELECT Count(ProdID) FROM Products WHERE Category = 'XYZ' AND Productstatus = 'TypeE') ") 

tickerquery.Append("INSERT INTO @Count_Tbl (Title, Total, TypeA, TypeB, TypeC, TypeD, TypeE SELECT @ALL_Title, @ALL_Total, @ALL_TypeA, @ALL_TypeB, @ALL_TypeC, @ALL_Decomm, @ALL_Running ") 

tickerquery.Append("INSERT INTO @Count_Tbl (Title, Total, TypeA, TypeB, TypeC, TypeD, TypeE SELECT @ABC_Title, @ABC_Total, @ABC_TypeA, @ABC_TypeB, @ABC_TypeC, @ABC_Decomm, @ABC_Running ") 

tickerquery.Append("INSERT INTO @Count_Tbl (Title, Total, TypeA, TypeB, TypeC, TypeD, TypeE SELECT @XYZ_Title, @XYZ_Total, @XYZ_TypeA, @XYZ_TypeB, @XYZ_TypeC, @XYZ_Decomm, @XYZ_Running ") 

tickerquery.Append("SELECT Title, Total, TypeA, TypeB, TypeC, TypeD, TypeE FROM @Count_Tbl") 

Dim results As IEnumerable(Of ProductCount) = _ 
    db.ExecuteQuery(Of ProductCount) _ 
    (tickerquery.ToString) 

e.Result = results 
End Sub
```

The error I get is

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'. at the tickerquery.ToString line
```

Is there another way of getting the results so that they can be bound to a Ticker?

Comment: Hi, I see that some variables are not declared: ALL_Decomm, ABC_Decomm, XYZ_Decomm, ALL_Running, ABC_Running, XYZ_Running

Comment: @jyparask Thanks... I had changed the names of the variables to make make them easier to read (all the same length) and missed some. All corrected. As I mentioned the SQL is OK as I have run the statements in SQL Manager and I get the desired 3 rows returned.

Comment: Can you try running in SSMS the result of tickerquery.ToString(). Have a break point and in the immediate window write ?tickerquery.ToString(). Put the result in SMs and run it. The error you are getting seems to be with SQL parser so better see what is the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed... in my conversion to a series of appends to a string builder I had deleted some closing brackets in the 3 insert statements.

I had

tickerquery.Append("INSERT INTO @Count_Tbl (Title, Total, TypeA, TypeB, TypeC, TypeD, TypeE SELECT @ABC_Title, @ABC_Total, @ABC_TypeA, @ABC_TypeB, @ABC_TypeC, @ABC_Decomm, @ABC_Running ")

and I should have had

tickerquery.Append("INSERT INTO @Count_Tbl (Title, Total, TypeA, TypeB, TypeC, TypeD, TypeE) SELECT @ABC_Title, @ABC_Total, @ABC_TypeA, @ABC_TypeB, @ABC_TypeC, @ABC_Decomm, @ABC_Running ")